# Remove the Delay in Expand/Collapse of a Table Row in Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, angular7

When I use tables, there is a delay in expanding/collapsing of accordions. The opening and closing also of accordions are not smooth. There are lots of solution provided online but none of these works on my task. Some of the solution use jquery but as much as possible we will apply techniques using CSS, HTML and/or Angular. Please help me...

Here are the following solution I have tried:
- encapsulate td in a div
- use transition techniques, e.g.  transition: flex 0.3s ease-out;
- setting the collapsible element's padding to 0

At component.ts

```
values = [{label: label1, content: content1},{label: label2, content: content2}]
```

At component.html

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
   </tr>
 </thead >

 <tbody id="accordion" *ngFor = "let value of values">

   <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true">
    <td>{{ value.label}}</td>
    <td>{{ value.label}}</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="collapse section" id="collapseOne">
    <td><div style="padding: 0;"> {{ value.content}} </div></td>
    <td><div style="padding: 0;"> {{ value.content}} </div></td>
   </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

At component.css

```
.section {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    flex: 1;
    -moz-transition: height .3s;
    -ms-transition: height .3s;
    -o-transition: height .3s;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s; 
    height: auto;
    padding: 0rem;
}

.section.collapsed {
    flex: 0;
}
```

Expected result is that the collapsing and expanding of the row is smooth and no delay

Comment: why not a simple solution *ngClass based?

Comment: Can you give an example alessandro?